# Javascript wait asynchronous response in synchronous function

Tags: javascript, forms, wait, synchronous

I guess my question is easy but I can not figure it out even searching for days.

There is my practical situation:

I have a form and would like to wait for the return of a stripe asynchronous function before submitting it to my backend as I need the response of the stripe API. I am then using the `onsubmit="return validate_form();">`
tag in order to manage that by myself in a javascript function.

```
<form action="/" method="get" id="test" onsubmit="return validate_test_form();">
  <button type="submit" id="iban-test" data-secret="">
    TEST
  </button>
</form>
```

```
function validate_test_form() {
  var stripe_result = stripe.confirmCardSetup(clientSecret)

  if (stripe_result.error) {
    // do things
  } else {
    // do other things
  }
  return true;
}
```

As a normal behavior, the form is submitted without waiting for the stripe response as the stripe function is asynchronous and the default `validate_test_form` function return is true. I am aware of **async/await/promise** concepts but don't see how I can use them to wait (block UI, with a spinner or other) for the response of stripe as a synchronous behavior.

I imagine this situation must be current and it must be lots way to perform what I am looking for. In either way, could you tell me what are the **best practices** in this situation.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: You can intercept the submit event by doing `event.preventDefault()`, and then manually submitting the form yourself, once the asynchronous operation is completed.

Comment: Used ```event.preventDefault()``` like this: ```<form action="/" method="get" id="test" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); validate_test_form();">```, it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to return `false` from `validate_test_form()` immediately (which will cancel submit action) and submit the form once response from Stripe is available.

Since `confirmCardSetup` returns a `Promise`, it won't block execution of your function. Instead, you can execute code once Promise returns a result by using `.then(func)`.

```js
function validate_test_form() {
  var stripe_result = stripe.confirmCardSetup(clientSecret)
  stripe_result.then(function(stripe_result) {

    // Hide the progress bar here

    if (stripe_result.error) {
      // do things
    } else {
      // do other things
      // Resubmit the form or use `stripe_result.setupIntent` if needed.
    }
  }); // this will return immediately, so we can continue.

  // Show a progress bar here or whatever

  return false;
}
```

Comment: Seems to solve my issue, I was wondering what should be the best practice, thanks everyone for your time.
Does someone has a practical example of a progress bar?